# R - make the same pipeline save two objects in a list

Tags: r, pipeline

Imagine that in the following example instead of `mtcars` I have some very long pipeline:

```
list(mtcars %>% 
         mutate(wt = wt + 1),
     mtcars %>% 
         mutate(wt = wt - 1))
```

In order to not have to write the same long pipeline twice, and also to not have to save the intermediate object resulting from the pipeline, I was hoping to use the `%T>%` pipe from `magrittr`

```
mtcars %T>%
    mutate(wt = scale(wt)) %>% 
    mutate(wt = wt-1)
```

But that doesn't work. So in which other way can I get the same list as in the first snippet of code, without breaking the pipeline and without having to write it twice?

Comment: Yes it does. Please reread my question. I am looking for a way to achieve the same output as in the first code. However, instead of `mtcars` I have a very long pipeline. I don't want to use it twice - notice how here I used `mtcars` twice. I am looking for a way to only use it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate a longer pipeline yet  keep the output short let us first take the first 6 rows and columns.  Then use brace brackets and dot as shown.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  head(6) %>%
  select(1:6) %>%
  { list(mutate(., wt = wt + 1), mutate(., wt = wt - 1)) }
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 3.620
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 3.875
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 3.320
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 4.215
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 4.440
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 4.460

[[2]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 1.620
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 1.875
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 1.320
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 2.215
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 2.440
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 2.460
```

This could also be done entirely in base R.

```
mtcars |>
  head(6) |>
  subset(select = 1:6) |>
  list(. = _) |>
  with(list(transform(., wt = wt + 1), transform(., wt = wt - 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   slice_head(n = 6) %>% 
   select(1:6) %>%
   list() %>%
   map2(c(1, -1), ~ .x %>% 
           mutate(wt = wt + .y))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 3.620
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 3.875
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 3.320
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 4.215
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 4.440
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 4.460

[[2]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 1.620
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 1.875
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 1.320
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 2.215
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 2.440
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 2.460
```